# T-SQL Change Data Capture log cleanup

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have enabled CDC on few tables in my SQL server 2008 database. I want to change the number of days I can keep the change history.

I have read that by default change logs are kept for 3 days, before they are deleted by  sys.sp_cdc_cleanup_change_table stored proc.

Does anyone know how I can change this default value, so that I can keep the logs for longer.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update the cdc_jobs.retention field for your database. The record in the cdc_jobs table won't exist until at least one table has been enabled for CDC.

```
-- modify msdb.dbo.cdc_jobs.retention value (in minutes) to be the length of time to keep change-tracked data
update
    j
set
    [retention] = 3679200 -- 7 years
from
    sys.databases d
inner join
    msdb.dbo.cdc_jobs j
        on j.database_id = d.database_id
        and j.job_type = 'cleanup'
        and d.name = '<Database Name, sysname, DatabaseName>';
```

Replace `<Database Name, sysname, DatabaseName>` with your database name.

Comment: Thanks. Another way I found was to run the following command: exec sp_cdc_change_job @job_type='cleanup', @retention=minutes

Answer (score 2):

Two alternative solutions:

1. Drop the cleanup job:

   ```
   EXEC sys.sp_cdc_drop_job @job_type = N'cleanup';
   ```
2. Change the job via sp:

   ```
   EXEC sys.sp_cdc_change_job 
   @job_type = N'cleanup',
   @retention = 2880;
   ```

Retention time in minutes, max 52494800 (100 years). But if you drop the job, data is never cleaned up, the job isn't even looking, if there is data to clean up. In case of wanting to keep data indefinitely, I'd prefer dropping the job.